# Corrupted strings coming from libapt-pkg

Tags: c++, ubuntu, apt, lib

I'm attempting to make a GUI package manager for Ubuntu similar to Synaptic which uses libapt but have run into a few strange bugs to do with getting information from the pkgCache. Specifically when using a pkgIterator and trying to access the FullName() and Name() properties but others like Section() are fine (you can look at documentation [here](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/libapt-pkg/classpkgCache_1_1PkgIterator.html#ae783a56d89afdb9e608d7543c46da951)).

Looking at the way Synaptic does it, it is pretty simple and I tried replicating it 1:1 with no luck.

```
const char *name() {
    const char *n = package->Name();
    if (n == NULL)
        return "";
    return n;
}
```

Which will usually return some garbage string that looks like a null termination was missed. The interesting thing is that all of the strings for packages in the same group from repositories will have the **same** garbage text while locally installed packages will have a NULL pointer and therefore will return an empty string.

Any ideas? I believe that I'm opening the pkgCache correctly and the iterator is not NULL. Theres also not many places to look online when debugging libapt so any references would be helpful as well!.

Comment: When and how are you checking the strings? Is the iterator or object pointed to by `package` still valid? Perhaps you should be returning a `std::string` instead, making sure you have a copy.

Comment: I'm making a copy of the pkgIterator itself and checking the string after the initial iteration but the same behavior exists if I pass it to a std::string or check the string within the initial iteration.

Comment: Copying iterators might not do deep copying, only shallow, so that might not be enough. A [mcve] would go a long way to help us help you better.

Comment: You might be right about the std::string part, accessing the FullName() method returns a std::string which behaves as expected before and after creating the new iterator object but the const char * of Name() still spits out garbage even if I pass it to a std::string first. Minimal reproducible example might be a bit difficult to provide but I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Also worth noting that `const char * Name()` has an extra `const` after it, would that cause issues?